# Hoisting does not work?

Tags: javascript

I stumbled upon this jsfiddle code sample about hoisting https://jsfiddle.net/phusick/h4bh2m4y/

```
fn1('hello');
fn2('world');

function fn1(message) {
    console.log('mgs1:', message);
}

var fn2 = function(message) {
    console.log('msg2:', message);
}
```

Surprisingly it does not work :

> Uncaught TypeError: fn2 is not a function

Is there any error in that program ?

Comment: var declared functions have to be declared before they are called, named functions can be found anywhere in your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript function declaration syntax: var fn = function() {} vs function fn() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-function-declaration-syntax-var-fn-function-vs-function-fn)

Answer (score 8):

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
// function declarations are hoisted
function fn1(message) {
    console.log('mgs1:', message);
}

// variable declarations are hoisted
var fn2;

fn1('hello');
fn2('world');

// assignments to a variable are not hoisted
fn2 = function(message) {
    console.log('msg2:', message);
}
```

The declaration of the `fn1` function is hoisted.

The declaration of the `fn2` variable is hoisted.

The assignment to the `fn2` variable is not hoisted.

Declarations are hoisted, assignments or initializations are not.

Function assignments like you are doing with `fn2` are different than function declarations such as `fn1`.  Assignments to variables with `var` are not hoisted, only the definition of the variable itself is hoisted.  So, at the point you try to call `fn2('world')`, `fn2` is still `undefined`.

Answer (score 5):

Function declarations are hoisted. (`function fn1(message) { }`)

Variable declarations are hoisted. (`var fn2`)

Assignments are **not** hoisted. (`fn2 = function(message) { }`)